# using date_to_str in mysql and I receive a truncation error that I dont understand

Tags: mysql

I am trying to reformat a string into a datetime field.

I don't understand why I am getting a warning below. I thought I was using this function in the exact way it was intended.

The warnings stop my next step of updating the table with this new field.

```
mysql> 

select reportdate, str_to_date(reportdate,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') as date
from dc_crash_data_tst limit 5;

`+------------------------+---------------------+
 | reportdate             | date                |
 +------------------------+---------------------+
 | 2010/11/25 08:30:00+00 | 2010-11-25 08:30:00 |
 | 2010/11/25 00:00:00+00 | 2010-11-25 00:00:00 |
 | 2010/11/29 18:10:00+00 | 2010-11-29 18:10:00 |
 | 2010/11/29 05:00:00+00 | 2010-11-29 05:00:00 |
 | 2010/11/29 05:00:00+00 | 2010-11-29 05:00:00 |
 +------------------------+---------------------+
```

5 rows in set, 5 warnings (0.00 sec)

```
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2010/11/25 08:30:00+00' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2010/11/25 00:00:00+00' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2010/11/29 18:10:00+00' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2010/11/29 05:00:00+00' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2010/11/29 05:00:00+00' |
```

Comment: It is expecting to parse the entire string.  Either remove the +00 before passing to str to date or include it in your format string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `reportdate` always includes '+00' at the end of its value, you should  add '+00' to your format string.

```
SELECT reportdate, str_to_date(reportdate,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s+00') AS date
FROM dc_crash_data_tst 
LIMIT 5;
```